# Selenium automation - running from a common folder

Tags: selenium, protractor, virtual-machine

I am trying to setup a shared folder on vm and from that folder setting up automation. Is there a way that all the people who have access to that folder can see automation running? See chrome instance running autmation?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, CI like Jenkins is used to run automation on VM and collect results.

But as for your question - to be able to view automation tests running on the browser on VM user should be logged in to that VM by Remote Desktop Connection.

Having a shared folder on VM can't help you to see tests running on VM because it doesn't mean users who have an access to it have a user account on that VM.

I would recommend creating one testing user account on that VM and share it with the team.

Run is performed on the agent, there is no way to see real time run on the agent without being logged in. You can record the run, save video to your shared folder, so users within access to that shared folder will have an access to saved videos.

Comment: Yes, we have Jenkins setup to run automation and collect results. I was wondering if there is a way that all users can see automation when it runs on jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Run is performed on the agent, there is no way to see real time run on the agent without being logged in. You can record the run, save video to your shared folder, so users within access to that shared folder will have an access to saved videos.

Comment: Makes sense. But when I login I do see instance of chrome which is running automation script. So, basically problem we are trying to solve is - Currently jenkins jobs are running from my local on vm but if I am not available for some reason - other people in my team can restart selenium server if needed. Thanks again for your comment.